# Is it possible to get the max value and min value from the given string 1stnumber-2ndnumber

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have string

x = "10-20"

Is it possible that I can get 
var max = 20;
var min = 10;

from the x I obtained?

[EDIT]
Also, what if I got
x = "1"
and also want to have
var max = 1;
var min = 1;

Is it possible to have a method that handled both cases?

Comment: Yes. Is the first number always the min value, or do you need to first get the two numbers and then test which one is smaller? Do you need input validation, or can that be assumed to have already happened? In any case, the simplest starting place is the string `.split()` method...

Comment: 1. Split a string by `-`. 2. Parse its parts to int.

Comment: Yes, first number always the small number, oh and I for get to mentioned sometimes I recieved the String as single number as well and I want to keep both as min and max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [string `.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get an array with the substrings:

```
var input = "10-20"
var numberStrings = input.split("-")     // ["10", "20"]
```

Then, convert the strings in the array to numbers and assign to your variables. I'd use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to do the conversion.

If the input didn't have a `"-"` in it, i.e., it was just one number, the return value from `.split()` will be an array with only one element that is the whole input string, so test for that:

```
var min = +numberStrings[0]
var max = numberStrings.length === 1 ? min : +numberStrings[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split those value to integer.

```
var arrayValue = x.split('-');
```

Use `javascript` function `Math.max(Value1, Value2)`
or 
`Math.min(Value1, Value2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to extract the numbers and then use the javascript `max` and `min` functions to get the largest and smallest values.

```
var x = '10-20';

var regex = x.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)/);
var first = Number(regex[1]);
var second = Number(regex[2]);
var maximum = Math.max(first, second);  // the largest of the two numbers
var minimum = Math.min(first, second);  // the smallest of the two numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
var nums = x.split("-");
nums[0] //10
nums[1] //20
```

Cast the string values to ints or Number if you need to calculate with them.
`parseInt(nums[0])`  OR `Number(nums[0])`

if you want the low and high regardless of how they come in you could add a sort to the array.

`x = "20-10";` OR `x = "10-20";`

```
var nums = x.split("-").sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});
alert("nums:"+nums[0]+" - "+nums[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular matching obtain string, convert strings to numbers

```
/(\d+)-(\d+)/.test("10-20") 
var min = RegExp.$1
var max = RegExp.$2
console.log(min)
console.log(max)
```